saving a matplotlib chart to a file degrades the quality
I'm creating a Matplotlib chart and then saving it to a file. (I've tried PNG, SVG, and PDF.) I want to email it to others.
When I view the chart in Pycharm, its looks great.  When I open the file for viewing, its the same data but the chart seems far less professional.
Is there some trick in Matplotlib for preserving the image quality of a chart when saving it?
Thank you for taking the time to read & perhaps answer my question.

Do you mean the resolution?  You can set dpi either when you instantiate your figure or in the call to savefig.

If you can [edit] your question and ① show us a MWE, ② completed with a screen dump of the Pycharm figure and ③ the saved PNG, we could reopen your question and MAYBE answer it.
